# Manter o estado selecionado na edição

Tags: php, jquery

Colegas.

Tenho um formulário de cadastro do qual o usuário ao escolher o estado, aparece automaticamente a cidade. Porém gostaria que na edição, a cidade já aparecesse selecionada. O código que tenho é esse:

```
<div class="item form-group">
                      <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="">Estado: <span class="required">*</span>
                      </label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <?php echo $metodos->listarEstados($visualizar->Estados); ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>                   
                      <div class="item form-group">
                      <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="">Cidade: <span class="required">*</span>
                      </label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <!--<span class="carregando">Aguarde, carregando...</span>-->
                        <select name="Cidades" class="select2_single form-control" id="cidades">              
                </select>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $("#estados").change(function(){
     var id = $(this).val();
     // var id = <?php echo $visualizar->Cidades; ?>;
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"exibe-cidades.php?id="+id,                    
            dataType:"text",
        success: function(res){                      
            $("#cidades").children(".cidades").remove();
            $("#cidades").append(res);
         }
      });
    });
  });
```

exibe-cidades.php

```
header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache' );
    header( 'Content-type: application/xml; charset="utf-8"', true );
      include("conexao.php");
    $id = $_GET['id'];
        $sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM crm_cidades WHERE estados_cod_estados='$id' ORDER BY nome");
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
              $nome=$row['nome'];
              $id=$row['cod_cidades'];
              echo '<option value="'.$id.'" class="cidades">'.utf8_encode($nome).'</option>';
        }
```

Comment: voce teria que de alguma forma verificar se esta em uma edição e ja trazer o select das cidades preenchidos de acordo com o estado e com a cidade escolhida com um `selected`

Comment: Isso. Já estou trazendo o estado, porém preciso apenas das cidades referentes ao estado que está cadastrada no banco de dados, do qual estou trazendo pela variável $visualizar->Cidades que está comentada dentro do jquery.

Comment: Na pagina de edição faça um looping para trazer as `<option>` preenchidas

Comment: Olá Daniel. Acho que não fui claro na minha dúvida. Na verdade consigo visualizar as cidades quando seleciono os estados, porém no cadastro, no campo de cidades, aparece "Selecione o estado acima" e ao selecionar, lista as cidades. O que quero é que na edição, apareça já o estado e a cidade selecionados, porém com o efeito de selecionar as cidades e aparecer automaticamente os estados, com a única diferença e não aparecer a frase e sim todas as cidades.

Comment: Sim, eu entendi, acho que não estou me fazendo entender, para editar o form ja vem com todos os dados preenchidos, certo? Então, você precisa construir uma array com todas as cidades baseadas no estado escolhido e gerar o `select` delas.